# Как исправить код Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, urllib

Есть код из книги по Python он должен выводить ссылки со страницы но выводит только окончание ссылки, что с ним не так?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import random
import re

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())


def getLinks(articleUrl):
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org" + articleUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return bsObj.find\
        ("div", {"id":"mw-content-text"}).findAll\
        ("a",href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))
        
links = getLinks("/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")


while len(links) > 0:
    newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links) - 1)].attrs["href"]
    print(newArticle)
    links = getLinks(newArticle)
```

Comment: Отформатируйте код нормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему вы решили, что он должен выводить полные ссылки? Ссылки на страницах **Википедии** конечно же относительные (как это обычно и делается на сайтах), элементы со ссылками выглядят примерно так все:

```
<a href="/wiki/National_day" title="National day">national day</a>
```

Скрипт получает эти относительные ссылки с сайта и выводит их как есть. Если хотите получать полные ссылки, вам нужно сделать полный `URL` из `URL` сайта **Википедии** и относительной части ссылки, как это и сделано в функции `getLinks` собственно:

```
html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org" + articleUrl)
```

Comment: @Алексей Да может быть и перевод кривой в книге, что не редкость в общем-то.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но я и пытаюсь понять почему не работает контентенация он выводит относительные ссылки а должен если я правильно понял должен вывести полные или я не прав?

Comment: @Алексей А где вы видите конкатенацию кроме скачивания той страницы, которая будет парситься? Больше нигде нет никакой обработки ссылок, они только ищутся и всё.

Answer (score 0):

В Вашем коде столько ошибок и нелогичных вещей, что лучше приложу код, который будет выдавать то же самое, но гораздо логичнее и эффективнее.

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from urllib.request import urlopen
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
        def __init__(self, site_name, *args, **kwargs):
                self.links = []
                self.site_name = site_name
                super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
                self.feed(self.read_site_content())
                self.write_to_file()
        def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
                if tag == 'a':
                        for attr in attrs:
                                if attr[0] == 'href':
                                        if not self.validate(attr[0]):
                                                self.links.append(attr[1])
        def validate(self, link):
                return link in self.links or '#' in link or 'javascript:' in link
        def read_site_content(self):
                return str(urlopen(self.site_name).read())
        def write_to_file(self):
              f = open('links.txt', 'w')
              f.write('\n'.join(sorted(self.links)))
              f.close()
input_link=input("Link:")
parser = MyHTMLParser(input_link)
```

P.S. Эта программа запишет все ссылки в файл - так мне кажется удобнее, но если Вам принципиально выводить в консоль, то просто замените

```
f = open('links.txt', 'w')
f.write('\n'.join(sorted(self.links)))
f.close()
```

На

```
print('\n'.join(sorted(self.links)))
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110964/discussion-on-answer-by-nezerix----python).